# Magento: missing Dataflow options in Admin Panel

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Magento 1.4.2 Admin Panel

Under `System > Import / Export` I have the following options:

```
Profiles
Advanced Profiles
```

I feel like I am missing `Dataflow - Profiles` and `Dataflow - Advanced Profiles`.

Were these present in Magento 1.4.2?

And if they were, how do I get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not exist in CE 1.4.2.

It first appears in CE 1.5.

Comment: Can you back that up at all? As I have a colleague here who is looking at his own installation of 1.4 and it has Dataflow options under that menu. Is this because his version has an extension installed?

Comment: Those two menu items are defined in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml. Consider downloading a fresh copy of 1.4.2 from magentocommerce.com, and comparing it with your copy.